# will_paginate 3.0.3 and data-remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

The will_paginate 3.0.3 view helper docs state, ":remote – sets to true the data-remote or remote attribute, depending of the inplementation of link_to" (sic, https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/the-will_paginate-view-helper).

Via Rails 3.2 Using "<%= will_paginate @collection, :remote => true %>" renders:

```
<div class="pagination" remote="true">
  <span class="previous_page disabled">← Previous</span>
  <em class="current">1</em>
  <a href="/people?page=2" rel="next">2</a>
  <a class="next_page" href="/people?page=2" rel="next">Next →</a>
</div>
```

Ie: there is no data-remote attribute applied to the link tag.s, but one to the pagination div (which looks like the unknown options fall-through described in the docs).  The last post here (https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/pull/100) states: "I see this pull request, and the referenced request, are both for the 2.3 version. The 3.0 version already includes this feature. Somebody should close this."

Accordingly, I'm expecting to see "data-remote='true'" in the pagination link tags generated by will_paginate so it can be handled by Rails UJS.

Am I off base or does anybody have this working?  Or, is a new LinkRenderer still required as described here:
http://jhonynyc.tumblr.com/post/4348012015/making-will-paginate-ajaxable-in-rails-3#notes

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this, I did get data-remote added to the links via a custom LinkRenderer.  As of today, the current version of WillPaginate operates differently than previously versions in this regard and I needed to follow the approach here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/158 and https://gist.github.com/1562185 .  Still curious about my orginal question, however.

Answer (score 5):

Might I suggest taking a look at [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)? I switched to it when I switched to Rails 3 and I really like it. It's clean, modular, and works great—and that includes AJAX pagination with `:remote => true`. Ryan Bates did a great [overview of Kaminari](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari?view=asciicast) awhile back.

I know this is side-stepping the issue, but sometimes it's better to side-step than keep charging forward. :-)

Comment: That is crazy simple to add Ajax based pagination (just `remote: true`)with Kaminari, thanks a lot for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

mislav's `will_paginate` gem unfortunately does not support `:remote => true` so far, even though the documentation states otherwise. But there is a very simple work around using jQuery. Consider the following example:

`page.html.erb`

```
<div id="collection_index">
  <% @my_collection.each do |x| %>
    <%= x.name %> <br />
  <% end %>     
</div>

<div id="collection_paginator" >
  <%= will_paginate( @my_collection ) -%>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#collection_paginator a').each( function() {
      $(this).attr( 'data-remote', 'true' )
      $(this).attr( 'data-type', 'html' )
      $(this).attr( 'data-replace', '#collection_index' )
    }) 
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work so well **99.9%**, give it a try =>
  https://gist.github.com/jeroenr/3142686